# Why I am getting this error when trying to create database running 'update-database'?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I am getting this error when trying to create and connect database first time.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Note: My server name is ".\SQLEXPRESS" while my Connection String is ( "Server=.; Database=DatabaseName; Integrated Security= true;" )

What steps should I take in order to fix this error, in addition to the one mentioned in the error message?

Comment: You connection string is wrong, or the server is down/not accepting requests/doesn't have ports open. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for examples

Comment: SOLVED: We should write the Connection String in this format :     "Server=.\\SQLExpress; Database=BookStore; Integrated Security=True;"

Comment: The database is in your local machine or in the cloud? If you're using sql server in azure, you need to set the firewall policy in portal before you connect to the database.

Comment: Actually it's in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Sql Express is installed as a named instance. That means you must connect like Server=(localhost)\SQLEXPRESS as opposed to just Server=localhost.
pay attention, there is a backslash between localhost and SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Yes, This was a typing mistake I update this.